# Remove Firebase observers with a FirebaseHandle does not work

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase Database. I followed [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html) but I can't figure it out why after removing `handleUserMessagesAdded` observable,  `handleUserMessagesAdded` still has a value and still observes if anything is added to the database. I also tried `removeAllObservers` but nothing changed. Is there anything that I am missing?!

```
class ChatController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

 var rootRef: DatabaseReference!
 var handleUserMessagesAdded: UInt!


 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   rootRef = Database.database().reference()
 }

 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewWillAppear(animated)
   observeMessages()
 }

 override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)

   // Remove listener with handle
   rootRef.removeObserver(withHandle: handleUserMessagesAdded)
 }

 deinit {        
    print("Deinit gets called after back button is clicked! ")
 }

 func observeMessages() {
   guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ,let toId = user?.id else {return}
   handleUserMessagesAdded = rootRef.child("userMessages").child(uid).child(toId).observe(.childAdded, with: { [unowned self] (snapshot) in
            let messageId = snapshot.key
            // Make the message to be seen for this user
            let childUpdates = ["/userMessages/\(uid)/\(toId)/\(messageId)": 1]
            self.rootRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

            self.rootRef.child("messages").child(messageId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [unowned self] (snapshot) in

                 guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}
                print(dictionary)
                // Reload CollectionView 

            }, withCancel: nil)

    }, withCancel: nil)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `removeObserver(withHandle: ...)` on the same reference that you registered it on.

So:

```
rootRef.child("userMessages").child(uid).child(toId).removeObserver(withHandle: handleUserMessagesAdded)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question, when we use `removeAllObservers `, isn't it supposed to go and remove all observers including child observers as you can guess from the name of it?!

Comment: Nope. It removes all observers on that specific ref only.